# FindViewByID returns null on nested views

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android app which has a navigation draw, structured like this:

activity_main.xaml:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xaml:

```xml
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to get the TextView `@+id/Name` however `FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RunnerName)` always returns `null`:

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
    //some stuff with `drawer`

    NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
             
    // this always returns null:  
    TextView runnerName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.RunnerName);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In `OnCreate()`, you'll have to call `FindViewById()` on `navigationView.GetHeaderView(0)` to get any `View`s in the `NavigationView` header. It takes a little bit for those to be loaded and attached to the `Activity`'s hierarchy, so calling `FindViewById()` on the `Activity` there will return null.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Mike, if you want to get the `Textview` in the `NavigationView`, you should got the `View` by `navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);`, then you can use following code to get the `TextView`

```
    NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
    navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View MyView=navigationView.GetHeaderView(0);
    TextView textView1 = MyView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
```

Here is running screenshot.

[image]